# Symmetric Olympiad inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Prove that for all positive reals $a, b, c$ this inequality holds:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{b^2 - bc + c^2} \ge \sum_{cyc}a$$

I have proved this in a very ugly way:

I multiplied with $(a^2 - ab + b^2)(b^2 - bc + c^2)(c^2 - ca + a^2)$ and with some work i managed to prove this with Schur. I find this way boring and time-consuming. My question is - Is there a nicer solution to this?

Source: [Mildorf Inequalities](https://artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/MildorfInequalities.pdf)

Comment: are you sure that holds for all reals?

Comment: Sorry, I meant positive will fix now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note by CS (with $\sum$ denoting cyclic sums):
$$ \sum \frac{a^3}{b^2-bc+c^2} \geqslant \frac{\left(\sum a^2 \right)^2}{\sum a(b^2-bc+c^2)}$$

Hence it is enough to show
$$\left(\sum a^2 \right)^2 \geqslant \left(\sum a\right) \cdot \sum a(b^2-bc+c^2)$$
$$\iff \sum a^4 + 2\sum a^2b^2 \geqslant \sum (2a^2b^2-a^2bc + b^3a+ ac^3)$$
which is just the fourth degree Schur inequality:
$$\sum a^4 + abc\sum a \geqslant \sum ab(a^2+b^2) $$
Equality is when $a=b=c$, or when any one variable is $0$ and the other two equal.

Answer (score 0):

Using only algebraic manipulation and the fact that a product of similarly-signed numbers is positive:
\begin{gather*}
\sum_\text{cyc} \frac{a^3}{b^2 - bc + c^2} - \sum_\text{cyc} a
=  \sum_\text{cyc} \frac{a^3(b + c) - a(b^3 + c^3)}{b^3 + c^3} \\
=  \sum_\text{cyc} \frac{ab(a^2 - b^2) - ca(c^2 - a^2)}{b^3 + c^3}
= \sum_\text{cyc} bc(b^2 - c^2)\left(
\frac{1}{c^3 + a^3} - \frac{1}{a^3 + b^3}\right) \geqslant 0,
\end{gather*}
because all three terms in the final cyclic sum are non-negative.

Comment: This argument can be considerably generalised, but I'm still working on the finicky proof of the general case, which I'll post later as a new question.